# Split wordpress in two

Tags: wordpress, split

I'am building a website for a company which has two sections, one repair section and one development section.
So the website has to be in two parts as well. 
It will be possible, on the first page, to choose which section you want to go.

But the repair section and the development section has it's own menu.

How do I split the wordpress in two, so that on both sections an other menu visible is?

Thank you

Comment: You could run two sites, either in two installations or under Wordpress Multisite. Then tweak the theme in each case, so that each can link to the other.

Comment: The scope on this question is too broad for anybody to write a single answer for you. There are also probably many ways that this task can be completed.

Essentially what you could do is use the Wordpress custom menu system together with a template page for each section.

See how far you get with this, and then come back when you have some code and I'm sure we'll be in a better position to help.

Comment: This is pretty difficult to answer, but from what little you have described, I'd stick with a single site and use two different Nav-Menu's. You can then set your templates up so that, depending on the page/post being viewed, it displays as the site you want, with the other menu somewhere else that you define.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  In order to get a good response it's important to understand how to ask a good question.  Give this page a read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague and makes it difficult to understand what you're real intention is.

However, since you tagged your question with `Wordpress` I assume you want a single Wordpress site with two main "areas".

With that in mind you'd probably want:

- A simple index/home page
- A "repair" page
- A "development" page
- ...and other repair or development pages

Your index/home page will just link to your repair / development landing pages ("landing page" is just a website term, nothing wordpress specific).  Each landing page can then link to additional pages.

This is all achievable with simple Wordpress pages.  Try reading through the Wordpress tuturoials to get familiar with the basics.

...and once you get started feel free to ask for help here.  Just try to make sure your questions are clear, specific, and mention what you've tried so far.

Comment: STW,
That's exactly what I mentioned.
Could you give me a link where I can find this in the tutorial?
Next time I would make sure my questions are more specific.
Thanks!